# Selecting different radio buttons goes to different html pages

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have 2 sets of radio buttons which I want to do the following:

1) When all selections are false, show validation messages.(This is working but when clicking 'Save' repeatedly it adds a blank row, how do I prevent this?).

2) If just Set 1 or Set 2 is selected show error message for the other on Save.

3). When Set 1 is selected, Set 2 selections need to take user to different pages depending on Yes or No.

Thanks in advance!!

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/cuyjJ/)

```
<span id="val1" style="display:none; color:red;"> Please make a selection</span> 
<strong>Radio Set 3</strong>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="attachYes" />Yes &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="attachNo" />
<label for="radio2">No</label>
<p> 
    <span id="val2" style="display:none; color:red;"> Please make a selection</span><strong>Radio Set 2</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="NotifYes" />Yes &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="NotifNo" />No
</p>
<p>
    <a href="#" id="Qbtn">Save</a>
</p>
```

JS

```
$('#Qbtn').click(function () {
    if ((!$('#attachYes').attr('checked') === true) && (!$('#attachNo').attr('checked') === true) && (!$('#NotifYes').attr('checked') === true) && (!$('#NotifNo').attr('checked')) === true) {
        //the validations are displaying correctly
        $('#val1').show().append('<br>');
        $('#val2').show().append('<br>');
    } else {
        if (($('#attachYes').attr('checked') === true) || ($('#attachNo').attr('checked') === true) && (!$('#NotifNo').attr('checked') === true) && ($('#NotifYes').attr('checked')) === true) {
            //the user should be taken to page1.html when clicking save and it isn't doing it                  
            window.location = "page1.html";

            //then how do I write if either of radio set 1 is true and #NotifNo of Radio set 2 is true go to page2.html.                
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bkSrD/)**

Try this:

```
$('#Qbtn').click(function () {
    if ($('#attachYes').prop('checked') && $('#NotifYes').prop('checked')) {
        //go to http://www.yahoo.com         
        window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    } else if ($('#attachYes').prop('checked') && $('#NotifNo').prop('checked')) { 
        //go to http://www.cnn.com                  
        window.location = "http://www.cnn.com";
    } else {
        //the validations are displaying correctly
        $('#val1, #val2').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

This does what you need, if I understood your question right. Do you really want to add `<br />` on every error? I added a fade in/out to avoid that. Hope its ok.

Comment: I have the <br> after the error message so it displays on a separate line, although I like the fadeOut.
I'll try to explain more what I need this to do.
If Neither Radio Set 1 or Radio Set 2 is selected show both val1 & val2.
If Radio Set 1 is selected & Radio Set 2 is not, show only val2.
If Radio Set 2 is selected & Radio Set 1 is not, show only val1.
If Radio Set 1 is selected and Radio Set 2 > attachYes is selected go to cnn.com.
If Radio Set 1 is selected and Radio Set 2 > attachNo is selected go to yahoo.com.

Comment: @squirc77, ok I understand. On my demo I added them on the html so they would'nt be many after clicking. You can also style them with CSS. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @squirc77, here is another option for the error messages with CSS http://jsfiddle.net/bkSrD/1/

Comment: Unfortunately I have not figured it out. I need 5 condition statements to do this and I am not skilled enough to write it.1) If Neither Radio Set 1 or Radio Set 2 is selected show both val1 & val2. 
2) If Radio Set 1 is selected & Radio Set 2 is not, show only val2. 
3) If Radio Set 2 is selected & Radio Set 1 is not, show only val1. 
4) If Radio Set 1 is selected and Radio Set 2 > attachYes is selected go to cnn.com. 
5) If Radio Set 1 is selected and Radio Set 2 > attachNo is selected go to yahoo.com.