# how to load multiple php page on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 1 html page containing 2 radio buttons and 2 different php pages page1.php and page2.php, I want to load page1.php on selecting first radio button and to load page2.php on selecting second radio button.

Any example or piece of JS code will help me a lot.

Here is the HTML code

```
<td align="center" class="bgcolor_03">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" class="gender" name="group" id="group" value="Sec"  />
        Secondary Section
        <input type="radio" class="gender" name="group" id="group" value="SSec"  />
        Seniour Secondary Section
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Done" />
    </form>
    </td>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to do this via AJAX I guess? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this code http://jsfiddle.net/bkSrD/ mention in post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533957/selecting-different-radio-buttons-goes-to-different-html-pages But I am new to Jquery so confused

Comment: When you say _load_ do you mean load it into your current HTML or change the entire page ? Because thats SO post can be used if you want to change the entire page.

Comment: @user26409021 No actually I mean to want go to another url

Comment: why do you event what to use jquery if you want to redirect? Do you know you can use ONLY php for this matter?

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi Yes php can also do but how? And I am not very much fond of Jquery, if I get some example how to do with PHP that will be great for me.

Comment: @srishti deb I post an answer with php for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your solution with PHP.
make sure you change your HTML file type to PHP.
**explanation** : in this example I check at the top if form is submitted or not.and if it is I check with radio button is checked and redirect user to your pages.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['group'])) { // "group" is mutual name of radio buttons
  switch ($_POST['group']) {
    case 'Sec':  // Value of first radio button
      header('Location: page1.php');
      break;
    case 'SSec':  // Value of second radio button
      header('Location: page2.php');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }    
}
?>
<td align="center" class="bgcolor_03">
  <form action="" method="POST" >
    <input type="radio" class="gender" name="group" id="group" value="Sec"  />
    Secondary Section
    <input type="radio" class="gender" name="group" id="group2" value="SSec"  />
    Seniour Secondary Section
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Done" />
  </form>
</td>
```

Comment: I used your code but after uploading the pages on server I am getting error - `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cbsecop2/public_html/kv1jamnagar.in/main.php:44) in /home/cbsecop2/public_html/kv1jamnagar.in/main.php on line 48` BUT working fine on localhost For your reference site is uploaded at http://kv1jamnagar.in/main.php

Comment: are you sure that you put my code on top of everything else on your main.php ? it must be on top of everything.

Comment: Yes I have done this mistake, now its working fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Html file declare 2 div:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<div id="page2"></div>
```

Use JQuery and do something like this:

```
function displayPage1()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page1.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success : function(data) {
            $('div#page2').html("");
            $('div#page1').html(data);
        },
        error : function(data) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
}

function displayPage2()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page2.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success : function(data) {
            $('div#page1').html("");
            $('div#page2').html(data);
        },
        error : function(data) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
}
```

Add on click event on your radio button to call the right function

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want the page to load.

1. You want to load the page via an ajax request into the current page holding the radio buttons
2. You want to click on a submit button after selecting the radio button and then have the right page load on its own.

Since you requested for JS code, i'm assuming that you are going with option 1

Your html will look something like this

```
<input type="radio" id="launch-page1" class="page-launcher" />
<input type="radio" id="launch-page2" class="page-launcher" />
<div id="hold-page1"></div>
<div id="hold-page2"></div>
```

Your JS (JQuery please) will look like this.

```
$(function(){
    $(".page-launcher").click(function () {
        if ( $(this).attr("id") === "launch-page1" ) {
            window.location.replace(path_to_page1);
        } else {
            window.location.replace(path_to_page2);
        }
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I simply want to go to another url like http://www. concate.in/page1.php or http://www. concate.in/page2.php depending on selected radio button. And jQuery is not all compulsory for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not a good practice if you used same ID for more than 1 element. So, I change your form, especially the radio button into this:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" class="gender" name="group" id="group1" value="Sec"  />
    Secondary Section
    <input type="radio" class="gender" name="group" id="group2" value="SSec"  />
    Seniour Secondary Section
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

I believe this jQuery below can give what you want..

jQuery

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    if($('#group1').prop('checked') == true){
        document.location.href = 'url here';
    }
    if($('#group2').prop('checked') == true){
        document.location.href = 'url here';
    }
});
```

Comment: Why showing syntax error in dreamweaver in line  `if($('#group2').prop('checked') == true{`

Comment: ok after adding ) and it work but on clicking on button after selecting radio button nothing happened. but url changed like this http://localhost/concatenate.in/kv1jamAmission/main.html?group=Sec

Comment: As I remember don't put your full-path url there, instead put only the  URI. e.g. `window.location.href = "/SI/hello"`